# how to convert node Buffer to string like console.log show

Tags: node.js

I want log the buffer to string, but I am not want to use buffer.toString() method

`console.log(new Buffer(12))`

show

`< Buffer 00 22 33 11 55 ...>`

but `console.log('buffer:' + new Buffer(12))`

show

`buffer: something can't read`

I want

`buffer: < Buffer 00 22 33 11 55 ...>`

Comment: You mean you want to print the same hex values without converting them to string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doing

```
var b = new Buffer([0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44]);
console.log(b);
// <Buffer 41 42 43 44>
```

is the same as doing

```
console.log(b.inspect());
```

whereas

```
var b = new Buffer([0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44]);
console.log('str' + b);
// strABCD
```

is the same as doing

```
console.log('str' + b.toString());
```

because using string concatenation using `+` automatically converts both sides of the operator to strings using `.toString()`. `console.log(...)` on the other hand converts its arguments to strings by calling `.inspect()` when possible.

The easiest way to do what you want to do is to just let console.log do its thing by passing it multiple arguments

```
console.log('buffer:', new Buffer(12))
```

Note, the `,` instead of a `+`, so instead of concatenating using `.toString`, you let `console.log` stringify each of its arguments on its own.

Comment: b.inspect() is just what I want